# Resizing WebView with a button

Tags: button, web, webview, resize, scale

I have an iPad app that uses a small part of the screen (top left) to show a website, and what I wanted to do was to resize the webview at a push of a button from within the app. So I launch the app with a small part of the screen taken up by the web view, and when I push a button scales the webview to full screen.

Thanks

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.facebook.com"]]];

[webView2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.youtube.com/"]]];

[webView3 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mobile.twitter.com/signup"]]];

[webView4 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/mobile"]]];
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Also, a little code sample might be helpful; an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), if possible.